# How to find Cassandra Version for a node which is down?

Tags: cassandra

It is easy to find Cassandra version of running Cassandra node. How to find the Cassandra version of a Cassandra node which is down or not started? Is there any file in which version is mentioned and which we can see?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should have file `lib/apache-cassandra-<version>.jar` file in the Cassandra directory.  You can also look into first line of the `NEWS.txt` file - it should have a version of the current version.